# getting java.nio.BufferUnderflowException while reading dbf file after using dbaseFileWriter.write(vals);

Tags: geotools, dbf

I'm using DbaseFileReader and DBaseFileWriter to read and update records in a dbf file. When I read the file first there is no error while opening DBF file but after I write some values to DBF using below method I'm getting the following Error

I've checked the value types in Object[] array, both type and count of values are equal to dbf file fields.

```
  public static boolean updateFeatureAtts(String shpFile, Map<String, Object> attsFeature) throws IOException {


    String file = CN.getMapDataFolder() + CN.FOLDER_LAYERS + "/" + shpFile.replace(".shp", ".dbf");

    DbaseFileWriter dbaseFileWriter = null;
    DbaseFileReader dbaseFileReader = null;
    ReadableByteChannel dbfChannel = null;
    WritableByteChannel writableByteChannel = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        dbfChannel = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
        dbaseFileReader = new DbaseFileReader(dbfChannel, true, Charset.forName("Windows-1256"));

        DbaseFileHeader header = dbaseFileReader.getHeader();

        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = attsFeature.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = iterator.next();
            if (entry.getKey().equals("FID")) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);


        writableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(fileOutputStream);

        dbaseFileWriter = new DbaseFileWriter(header, writableByteChannel, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), TimeZone.getDefault());

        Object[] vals = attsFeature.values().toArray();

        dbaseFileWriter.write(vals);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally { 

        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();
        if (fileOutputStream != null)
            fileOutputStream.close();
        if (dbaseFileReader != null)
            dbaseFileReader.close();
        if (dbaseFileWriter != null)
            dbaseFileWriter.close();


    }
    return true;
}
```

this is the error

```
      java.nio.BufferUnderflowException at 
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java: 164)
at org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader.read(DbaseFileReader.java: 417)
at org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader.readRow(DbaseFileReader.java: 314)
at com.edsab.gedat.util.DBaseFileHandler.findRecord(DBaseFileHandler.java: 174)
at com.edsab.gedat.adapter.AttributePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(AttributePagerAdapter.java: 102)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java: 1003)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java: 1217)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java: 1085)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java: 273)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java: 777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java: 590)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java: 559)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java: 763)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6918)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 1199)
```

Comment: This does not appear to be a GIS-centric issue. [so] proper seems more appropriate, since this is a coding issue (failure to flush properly). You should always instrument your code with diagnostics when you are having difficulty.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you are removing the FID and so end up one value short when writing. But this approach is fraught with dangers as the shapefile spec relies on an exact ordering match between the .shp and .dbf files. I would try to use a shapefile writer and features to handle this task.